Instance a different sets of geometry on different parts of mesh by index
I have a mesh circle that has some deleted verts. Each seperate curve of this must have a different instance of geometry instanced to it. For example there are 4 parts. Curve index 0 must have cubes, curve index 1 have spheres and so fourth. I have some working on a repeat zone but still struggling to get all the elements to show up.
Bear in mind I am using a repeat zone because the amount of segments of the circle will change (not set to 4, it could be 5 or 6, and the position of the deleted parts also adjusts dynamically.
Is there a way to do this without repeat zone ?
Thank you!




Reading again your question, do you have a Curve with many Splines as input geometry to the GN modifier ? Or do you have a Mesh with Islands ?

its a mesh with islands

(Using Blender 4.2.1)

1. Objects to spawn are collected by a Geometry to Instances node.
2. With activation of the Pick Instance property, the Instance Index is based on the Island Index of the spawning point.
The Instance Index value is computed as the Island Index modulo the number of instances in the collection. So with 4 islands and 3 objects to spawn, index 0 (the cube) is reused for mesh islands 0 and 3 (because 0 mod 3 = 3 mod 3 = 0). Consequently, this setup is dynamic whatever the number of islands and the collection size.
Resources:
(Blender 4.2.1+)

you are a wizard. It was so much simpler than I was trying with repeat zones and nested zones. Cheers!
